# Delete space in String Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, trim

I have a string: **'__*that is image'***;
I want delete spaces(__) in front of 'that' (result is: **'that is image'**)
How can I do.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = ' that is image';
str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,""); //Removes left and right extra spaces
```

Comment: Maybe just use the first half of the regex since they only seem to want leading spaces removed. Otherwise, I always use this as a polyfill in case the browser doesn't support `trim` natively

Answer (score 3):

Javascript 1.8 onward has a `trim()` function. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

You could use it like this:

```
var str = "   that is an image  ";
alert(str.trim());//"that is an image";
```

As MDN describes to ensure full support you could add a prototype method like this:

```
if(!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = '  that is image';
str = str.replace(/\s/g,"");
console.log(str);
alert(str);
```

Comment: Right idea, but I don't think they are actually using the `_` character, since they specified "spaces" and are just using that to display where they mean the spaces area.